# If efficiency is more important, then why condenser is used in boiler?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, temperature, work

What's the real reason behind condenser?

some says,

1. Without condenser, back-pressure will be created in turbine.
2. After Expansion in turbine, entropy will be maximum so it must be cooled to reduce entropy    (Maximum entropy means, it cannot be converted to useful work)

3.if condenser is not there, it will violate second law of thermodynamics.how?

4.Thermodynamic cycle is not completed without heat rejection(condenser). what it means?

What could be the direct reason for condenser presence?

Comment: Two words: _boiler scale_.  Boiler scale is any kind of mineral crud that precipitates out of the water, sticks to everything in the system, and eventually clogs up the whole works. The most cost effective way to prevent boiler scale is to re-use the water in a closed loop instead of continually boiling fresh, mineral-laden water and then venting the steam to atmosphere.

Comment: The most important use for a condenser in most (relatively) modern steam engines is to reuse the feed water I suspect.

Comment: thanks for comment, thermodynamic reason behind condenser presence?

Comment: Re, "thermodynamic reason," Maybe start reading from here: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condenser is not needed to produce power from the turbine.  There will be a pressure drop across the turbine, as the turbine receives high pressure steam, develops shaft work from that steam, and exhausts the steam to atmosphere.

Having said that, the water that goes to the boiler must be purchased from some source, it must be treated to remove dissolved oxygen and other gasses, and it must be boiled at high pressure to produce the steam that goes to the turbine.  Sending turbine exhaust steam directly to atmosphere means that a LOT of water must be purchased and treated to keep the turbine running.  It is much more economical, both in terms of the amount of water that is purchased, and in water treatment costs, to condense the turbine exhaust steam and route it back to the boilers in a closed loop.  This option also gives you the opportunity to put a condenser directly downstream of the turbine and condense the turbine exhaust at a pressure lower than atmospheric pressure (vacuum condensing), which produces more pressure drop across the turbine and hence, more shaft work per pound of steam input.

While there may be thermodynamic considerations involved in this problem (e.g., the opportunity for vacuum condensing), economics is a major "driver" in using closed-loop turbine systems.

Comment: you gave explanation for the 1st point of my question,but i need a exact answer with justification.

Comment: @HvacEngineer, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If a turbine is run "open loop," where hot waste gases escape into the atmosphere, no condenser is needed. A condenser is only needed when you run "closed loop."  Practically speaking, it is very wasteful of water to run open loop, so you typically see closed loop systems, which have to recycle the water.

It would actually be theoretically possible to operate a turbine without a condenser.  You'd simply have to pump the cooled steam into the boiler to be heated.  You'd have to do so with a pump that has enough head-pressure to ensure the heated steam can't flow backwards.  Practically speaking, we are *much* better at pumping liquids efficiently than we are gasses.  Thus, from a practical perspective, it's worth taking the hit to condense the steam into water, pump the water (with the required head-pressure needed to keep the cycle flowing in one direction), and re-vaporize it in the boiler.

Comment: Cort Ammon, that "pump" that you are describing would necessarily have to be a steam compressor.  If you run steam through a turbine, then use a compressor to produce high enough pressure to send that steam to the boiler, the net gain in shaft work is very small (and probably negative).  No practical application in the world is going to try this.

Comment: @DavidWhite I don't think it has to be a steam compressor.  I haven't run the idea to ground, but a batch process where the heating is alternated with moving steam might work with acceptable performance, in theory.  It would be similar to a gun breech where one alternates between moving bullets and containing high pressure explosions.  In practice, I agree, it is not a solution that is practical.

Comment: Cort, a batch process is impractical in this application.  That is why boilers operate on a continuous process.

Comment: @DavidWhite Agreed.  That's why every paragraph I wrote states that practically speaking, this is not done.  However, since several of the options the OP presents suggest that the issue is theoretical rather than practical, I found it useful to separate the theoretical and practical models.

Comment: @cort you gave explanation for the 2nd point of my question.But mine is, which one of the answer is perfect and justify.

Comment: @HvacEngineer I don't knkow if any of the answers are perfect, but I'd say #1 is the closest.  If I was trapped with this question, I'd want to know what they think they would replace the condenser with? There's a tongue in cheek answer that "You need the condenser because, if you took it out, you'd have a big hole where the condenser was and it'd leak the steam out."  But the real reason is "because it's practical." I like #1 because, if I replaced the condenser with a plain ol' pipe, it'd be accurate... there'd be backpressure. But that doesn't mean I couldn't replace it with something else.